# whats the meaning of "verb=LIST" in kubernetes apiserver logs and alerts?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, devops, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Recently i renewed certificates on cluster using kubeadm alpha certs renew and then I saw logs in Kubernetes Apiserver pods as below:

`kubectl -n kube-system logs  --tail 10 kube-apiserver-master-1`

```
I1011 07:27:25.703052       1 trace.go:116] Trace[989041745]: "List" url:/api/v1/persistentvolumeclaims (started: 2022-10-11 07:27:22.702071048 +0000 UTC m=+165036.176710383) (total time: 3.000954622s):
```

and i received too many alerts from Alertmanager(I'm using Prometheus-operator on Kubernetes).
this is a sample alert:

```
FIRING
Alert:  - critical
Description:
Details:
  • alertname: KubeAPIErrorsHigh
  • cluster: myCluster
  • prometheus: monitoring/prometheus-prometheus-oper-prometheus
  • resource: persistentvolumeclaims
  • severity: critical
  • verb: LIST
```

Prometheus metric that is created by Prometheus-operator is:

```
expr: sum
  by(resource, subresource, verb) (rate(apiserver_request_total{code=~"5..",job="apiserver"}[5m]))
  / sum by(resource, subresource, verb) (rate(apiserver_request_total{job="apiserver"}[5m]))
  > 0.1
```

I want to now are there any problems in the cluster or not.

Answer (score 0):

`verb: LIST` as in HTTP verb. (GET, POST, PUT, LIST etc). Whats most likely happening is something is trying to LIST all the PVC's and thats taking too long or failing. In which case yes you need to look into why.